# Can you help me identify these SMD components?

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I'm trying to repair a Nintendo Switch. I've noticed that the board is missing 2 SMD components. The little one seems to be a 0 ohm resistor, but I still can't identify the one with 5 legs (3+2.)

I've marked in red the components that I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: The "little one" is more likely an inductor than a resistor.

Comment: If components are "missing", it's more likely that they were never populated in the first place. It's not easy to remove such tiny parts without meaning to.

Answer (score 0):

Given the two thick ground trace, as well as two cap, I would bet on some LDO voltage regulator for whatever is connected to the ribbon cable.

If you can power up the board you can check the voltages across the two caps, if they are different, it's most likely what it is and then will narrow down your search given the package.